# How to detect the change of a GtkStack or GtkStackSwitcher

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

What I'm trying to-do is detect when a user changes the visible child in a GtkStack.

I'm using a GtkStackSwitcher as a visible way to display buttons as per this design:

[image: pic]

Thus - when a person clicks/toggles one of those buttons I want to perform some processing.

Which event should I connect to achieve this?

I've looked at both [Gtk.Stack](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Stack.html#signals) and [Gtk.StackSwitcher](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/StackSwitcher.html#signals) but I dont see any obvious signals.  Any thoughts on the best way to proceed?

These don't appear to be standard buttons - so a 'clicked' event I dont think applies in this scenario.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 Gtk+3.10, python3

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`visible-child` is the property you are looking for. Use the `notify` signal to get notified of changes:

```
def vc_changed(stack, gparamstring):
    print("visible child changed")

my_stack.connect("notify::visible-child", vc_changed)
```