# Is there a way to sense when the GTK stack changes to a different page

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

I am writing a program using Gtk3 and Python and I need to detect when the user switches stack pages using a Gtk.StackSidebar. I have searched for a way to do this but couldn't find any information. Is there a way to achieve this functionality or is it not a supported feature in Gtk3? I believe there should be a way to do this, but perhaps I haven't searched thoroughly enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to track stack page changes, and not if the stack page changed specifically using the sidebar. This is achievable with the help of `notify` signal to track currently visible child in the stack using its `visible-child` property. You can get the stack associated with a sidebar with `sidebar.get_stack()` if needed.

A minimal working example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# main.py
#
# Run: python3 ./main.py
#
# Author: Mohammed Sadiq <www.sadiqpk.org>
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1-or-later OR CC0-1.0

import sys

import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import GLib, Gtk


class MyApplication(Gtk.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(application_id="org.example.SomeStack")
        GLib.set_application_name("Example Stack")

    def _stack_visible_child_changed(self, stack, pspec):
        name = stack.get_visible_child_name()
        print(f"stack child: {name}")

    def do_activate(self):
        stack = Gtk.Stack()
        side_bar = Gtk.StackSidebar(stack=stack)
        box = Gtk.Box()
        box.add(side_bar)
        box.add(stack)

        stack.connect("notify::visible-child", self._stack_visible_child_changed)

        for i in range(0, 6):
            widget = Gtk.Label(label=f"Hello {i}")
            stack.add_titled(widget, f"widget{i}", f"Hello{i}")

        window = Gtk.ApplicationWindow(application=self, default_width = 300, default_height=400)
        window.add(box)
        window.show_all()
        window.present()


app = MyApplication()
exit_status = app.run(sys.argv)
sys.exit(exit_status)
```

Comment: The notifying solution helped. However, the example doesn't have a signifying of whether it uses Gtk 3 or Gtk 4 so it by default uses Gtk 4. Gtk 4 doesn't have box.add.

Answer (score 0):

While @Mohammed Sadiq's answer is what OP was looking for, answering this question made me work quite a bit. I work with Gtkmm, not PyGtk, so I tried doing this in C++. Examples were non-existent out there, so I decided I would post my solution here, in case someone ever needs it in C++ (or in C, it is really close too). It basically boils down to what Mohammed did: *connecting to the `notify` signal for the `visible-child` property of the `Gtk::Stack`*. Here is how I did it in C++ (which a pinch of C, see below):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm.h>

class MainWindow : public Gtk::ApplicationWindow
{

public:

    MainWindow();

private:

    void OnPageChanged()
    {
        std::cout << "Page changed!" << std::endl;
    }

    Gtk::Stack m_stack;
    Gtk::Label m_pageOne;
    Gtk::Label m_pageTwo;

    Gtk::StackSidebar m_sideBar;

    Gtk::Box m_layout{Gtk::Orientation::ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL};

};

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    // Registering widgets inside the stack:
    m_pageOne.set_text("A first page.");
    m_stack.add(m_pageOne, "Page 1", "Page 1");

    m_pageTwo.set_text("A second page");
    m_stack.add(m_pageTwo, "Page 2", "Page 2");

    // Important: Connecting to the `notify` signal on the
    // stack's `visible-child` property. This will fire the
    // `OnPageChanged` function every time the property is
    // changed (every time the users changes the visible
    // page, through the side bars (thanks to Mohammed Sadiq
    // for this non-C version).
    m_stack.connect_property_changed("visible-child", [this](){OnPageChanged();});

    // Connecting the stack to the stack bar:
    m_sideBar.set_stack(m_stack);    

    // Adding everything to the layout:
    m_layout.pack_start(m_sideBar);
    m_layout.pack_start(m_stack);

    add(m_layout);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.examples.base");
  
    MainWindow window;
    window.show_all();
  
    return app->run(window);
}
```

Sources:

1. An [example in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182792/how-to-detect-the-change-of-a-gtkstack-or-gtkstackswitcher) (my starting point).
2. The [solution described above, in GTK](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/what-is-the-signal-for-stack-page-switch/8950) (by Ebassi on Gnome discourse).
3. The GTK C API for the [`notify` signal](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/signal.Object.notify.html). I have found no equivalent in C++.

Compiled using Gtkmm 3.24.20 with `g++`.

Comment: Reading the documentation, I see that you can do something like `m_stack.connect_property_changed("visible-child", sigc::ptr_fun(&on_property_visible_child_changed));` to achieve the same.

Comment: Answer updated, what you suggested works, I have no idea why I could not find this in my documentation the first time. Thanks!